# Characterizing Totally Ramified Extensions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I am trying to understand two portions of the proof of Theorem 2.4 [here](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Ecais/Prelim/LocalFieldExt.pdf).

Let $L/K$ be an extension of nonarchimedean fields. Say the valuation on $K$ is $v$ extending to $w$ on $L$. A polynomial $f = a_nx^n + ... + a_1x + a_0 \in K[x]$ is called **Eisenstein** if $v(a_0) = 0$, $v(a_i) \geq 1$ for all $1 \leq i < n$, and $v(a_n) = 1$.

Let $\pi_L$ be a uniformizer of $L$. First, why does every root $\alpha_i$ of a degree $n$ Eisenstein polynomial over $K$ having extended valuation $w(\alpha_i) = 1/n$ force the ramification index $e = (w(L^*):v(K^*)) = v(\pi_L)$ to be at least $n$?

Second, suppose you have $\alpha \in L$ such that $w(\alpha) = 1$ and that $L/K$ is totally ramified; that is $e := v(\pi_L) = [L:K]$.  It follows that the $1,\alpha,...,\alpha^{n-1}$ form a $K$-linear independent set, so

$$a_0\alpha^n + a_1\alpha^{n-1} ... + a_{n-1}\alpha + a_n = 0$$

The proof then claims that it must be the case that there exist $i,j$ such that $w(a_i\alpha^i) = w(a_j\alpha^j)$ are of maximal valuation. Why? And why does this then force $f = \sum a_ix^i$ to be Eisenstein?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing with various different normalizations of the valuation, but let's agree to say that $v(\pi_K) = 1$.

If $L/K$ is a finite extension, and $\pi_L$ is a uniformizer of $L$, then since $\pi_K \in L$ you can write

$$\pi_K = u \cdot \pi^e_L$$

for some unit $u \in \mathcal{O}^{\times}_L$. The number $e$ here the ramification index. The valuation $v$ extends to $L$ and you see you have the formula

$$1 = v(\pi_K) = e v(\pi_L)$$

so $v(\pi_L) = 1/e$.

Now suppose that $L/K$ is Eisenstein, so $L = K(\alpha)$. From the Newton Polygon, you can deduce that $v(\alpha) = 1/n$. But you can also write $\alpha = u \pi^r_L$ in $L$ for some $r$, and then you see that

$$1/n = v(\alpha) = r v(\pi_L) = r/e,$$

so $e = nr$. But you also know that $e \le n$, because otherwise $\pi_L$ could not satisfy a degree $\le n$ polynomial over $K$. So you deduce not only that $e = n$ but also that $r = 1$, that is, that $\alpha$ is a uniformizer of $L$.

For the second question, the $p$-adic valuation has the following behavior: if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are elements of $L$, then $v(\alpha + \beta) \ge \min\{v(\alpha),v(\beta)\}$. But it actually satisfies a stronger property: if $v(\alpha)$ and $v(\beta)$ are *different*, then $v(\alpha+\beta) = \min\{v(\alpha),v(\beta)\}$. By induction, that means that if you add together $p$-adic numbers all with different valuation then the valuation of the sum is the smallest valuation of any term. But the sum in this case is $0$, which has infinite valuation, so this can't happen, that is, there must be two terms with the same *minimal* (not maximal) valuation.

Now back to the particular sum. First of all, we want to make sure we don't get confused about valuations. The implicit normalization here is that $\alpha$ is a uniformizer of $L$ and $v(\alpha)=v(\pi_L)=1$. Then this implies that $e=n=[L:K]$ and then $v(\pi_K)=n$. That is, the valuation of any element of $K$ is divisible by $n$. But now look at the sum.

One can certainly assume that that $a_i$ are all in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and are not all divisible by $\pi_K$. That means they all have valuations which are divisible by $n$. Moreover, there is at least on $k$ with $a_k$ a unit. Consider the two terms of minimal valuation: since $v(\alpha) = 1$ and $v(a_i) \in n \mathbf{Z}$, the valuation of the $k$th term is $k \bmod n$. So the only way that two terms can have equal valuation is if they are the first and last terms. Moreover, these are the terms of smallest valuation. The valuation of $a_0 \alpha^n$ is at least $n$ since $a_0$ is assumed to be in $\mathcal{O}_K$. But we are assuming that there is a $k$ with $a_k$ a unit; the corresponding term must have valuation exactly $v(a_k \alpha^k) = k \le n$. So the only way the first and last terms can have the smallest equal valuation and the

1. $a_0$ is a unit, so $v(a_0 \alpha^n) = n$.
2. $a_n$ is exactly divisible by $\pi_K$, so $v(a_n) = n$.
3. $a_k$ for $1 \le k \le n-1$ are all divisible by $\pi_K$ --- otherwise $v(a_k \alpha^k) = k < n$.

These together say exactly that the polynomial is Eisenstein.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. A number of these details would have been lost on me.